# fork() and wait() in C

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

I am trying to learn the fork() and wait() system calls. If I run this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main (){

printf("Hi, I am the parent with pid %d \n ",getpid());

int rc = fork();

printf("Fork returned :   %d \n ",rc);

printf("I am the process with pid %d \n ",getpid());

wait(NULL);
return 0;
}
```

I get the output as expected on the terminal  :

```
Hi, I am the parent with pid 3639 
 Fork returned :   3640 
 I am the process with pid 3639 
 Fork returned :   0 
 I am the process with pid 3640
```

However , If I remove  `wait(NULL)` , I get a strange output on the terminal :

```
    Hi, I am the parent with pid 3715 
     Fork returned :   3716 
     I am the process with pid 3715 
     John@John-VirtualBox:~/Fork5$  Fork returned :   0 
     I am the process with pid 3716
```

I totally understand that , we use `wait()` to make the parent process waits for the child to end executiion so that we can remove it from the process table and deallocate its PID . But here , if I remove the `wait` , we see that the terminal is called again :

```
         John@John-VirtualBox:~/Fork5$  Fork returned :   0 
         I am the process with pid 3716
```

And even it doesn't return again back . I don't understand what this have to do with the functionality of `wait` ? Or in other words , why `wait` will fix this issue ?

Comment: The terminal isn’t being “called”. The parent process terminates, so the shell issues a prompt. The child process then terminates and prints output to the terminal.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Thanks alot , please add your comment as an answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of events appears to be:

1. The shell is the parent process to your program. When it `fork`s your program your program inherits the standard streams (to the terminal).
2. Your program `fork`s a child process which *also* inherits the standard streams (to the terminal).
3. When your parent process terminates, the shell notices (because it is `wait`ing) and issues a prompt to the terminal.
4. However, your program’s child has not yet terminated, so after the shell issues its prompt the child prints its output (and then terminates).

You will notice that the shell does *not* issue a second prompt after the child terminates. (The shell does not know anything about your child process.)

##### Order of output

The fact that you get *complete* output lines (instead of anything interleaved) is because the standard streams for all processes are in *line oriented* mode.

However, there is no guarantee of order between processes. The OS scheduler can order them any way it wants. Your child could have printed before the parent.

:O)

Comment: Just to check my understanding , the parent has terminated first because it didn't wait for the child to finish execution. However , in case of a call to wait () the parent will finish its code and then it waits for the child to finish before termination. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.